# Why does UITableView footer appear over the top of the last cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which contains a bunch of cells (dynamically generated) and it displays a footer message showing the last updated time. The issue I'm having is that on the first loading of the `UITableView` it seems to display the footer over the top of the last cell. Once you reload the data it displays it correctly though.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

**Initial loading:**

[image]

**After reloading:**

[image]

The following is the logic I use for establishing the footer message to display:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    var title = ""
    if (section == kSectionA) {
        if (!self.hasInternet) {
            title = "No Internet Connection"
        } else {
            if (self.dataToDisplay) {
                title = "Last Updated: xx:xx AM"
            } else {
                title = "No results found."
            }
        }
    }

    return title
}
```

Comment: Because you failed to tell the view controller how tall the cell is.

Comment: Could you provide the content of:
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
I believe you need to increase the height of the row in that function.

Comment: Also may you solve it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030788/11543623).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the Tableview how big the footer is from the beginning.Try using this code but with your values.

Tells the Tableview how big the footer is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

return footerView
}
```

Tells the footer how big the footer is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
return 40.0
}
```

That should solve you problem.

Comment: Probably that code solve most of the things related to this problem, but I'm seeing he's using titleForFooterInSection instead of viewForFooterInSection. But the user should respond.