# Prevent footer overlapping tableViewCell in UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this table view which works how i want it to however i have a problem where the footer overlap the cells in the table view as seen in[image: this image]

How can i prevent this? This is my code for the footer

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
    //    self.myTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
    let sectionString = Array(foodArray.keys)[section]


      for value in caloriesArray[sectionString]! {
        calories += value
       }
       totalCalories += calories

      print(calories)
      print(totalCalories)
      let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(footerView.frame.origin.x - 15, footerView.frame.origin.y, footerView.frame.size.width, 20))

       label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

       label.text = "Total Calories: \(calories) "

      footerView.addSubview(label)
       calories = 0
  return footerView
  }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

  return 20.0
}

@IBAction func addFoodTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let sectionString = Array(foodArray.keys)[indexPath.section]

    foodArray[sectionString]?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    caloriesArray[sectionString]?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    print(foodArray)
   viewDidAppear(true)
  }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you calling `viewDidAppear` when you tap on a cell?

Comment: ah I was testing something but it's been removed

Comment: how were you able to get sections to add up their totals in the section footer? I've been stuck on this for weeks.  it would mean a lot to me if you could help here's my email evelyncphillips94@gmail.com thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that, Just make Style `Grouped` as shown below: [image: here]

Comment: code is here
```swift

yourTableView.init(frame: .zero, style: .grouped) // Frame needs to be sized for you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some padding to the bottom of the content so that it doesn't overlap with the footer:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, FOOTER_HEIGHT, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, so this is more so for others that encountered this (like myself).

The floating section footer is default behavior from my understanding.  There are a couple of options that I can think of:

Provide your footer view with a background color (footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white) thus cleaning up the overlap.

or

Replace the section footer with a custom "Total Calories" cell that you add to the table after the last cell in that section, effectively acting like a footer cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. If you have modified the standard contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior of the tableView, you must adjust the tableView contentInset property to take into account the total height of the views at the bottom of the UITableView, like the tab bar. If contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior is set to "automatic" (or you didn't change the default value), then set the clipsToBounds property of your footer view to true so that its child views cannot be painted outside the footer view layer's frame. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to override this method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

Comment: this did not fix my problem. Is there any way to make the footer fixed in its position?

Answer (score -2):

Of course it overlaps. This is how footers and header work in `UITableView`s. You can set the `footerView.backgroundColor` to `UIColor.gray`, for example, to make it look better.

Answer (score -2):

Just set your label's background color to `UIColor.white.` and you are done !

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```