# UITableView footer overlaps cell in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11

In my tableView, I am using **automatic row & section footer height**. It looks good on iOS 10, but on iOS 11 the section footer overlaps the cell on landscape.

Is there some new iOS 11 property that I'm not setting that's causing this?

This is what it looks like running on iOS 10:

[image]

This is what it looks like running on iOS 11:

[image]

I have xib with a tableView constrained to the edges of the view. I'm setting row/footer/header height in IB:

[image]

Comment: Add your code work and storyboard constraints. There are many ways to create header & footer, so specify which way you using.

Comment: thanks @dahiya_boy, I am using built-in headers and footers. My xib is a tableView with constraints to the edges (0, 0, 0, 0), that's it

Comment: Add the question part into question. Describe your question properly.

Comment: Yes, may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030788/11543623) resolve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Do you set your custom heights for header and footer?

Your table view delegate should implement this methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

which should return appropriate values.

If you return smaller values then your header and footer views have, then they may overlap.