# How do I calculate the total amount of cells in section?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore, sections

Im trying to calculate the total calories for every section in the section footer

so far Ive failed at getting daily total calorie count results in the footer of every section

there are three test codes that give me 3 different results:

**Test Code 1** - puts "0" in every footer

**Test Code 2** - gives me something close to an accurate results but adds up the total for all the cells in every section and places the overall total in the footer(s)

**Test Code 3** - gives off random numbers as a result in the footer of every section

(as seen in image below)

when im trying to get the results as seen in the far right of the image

[image: total in section footers]

[Prevent footer overlapping tableViewCell in UITableView - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391095/prevent-footer-overlapping-tableviewcell-in-uitableview-swift/39988299#39988299)

https://github.com/Dassine/ShoppingCart

```
import UIKit

class CalorieViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var dailyCalories: [DailyCalories] = []
    var groupedCalorieItems: [String: [DailyCalories]] = [:]
    var dailySectionTitle: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var calorieTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dailySectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let calories = dailySectionTitle[section]
        return groupedCartItems[calories]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let calorieCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieCell") as! CalorieCell

        let calories = dailySectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let caloriesToDisplay = groupedCalorieItems[calories]![indexPath.row]
        calorieCell.configure(withCalorieItems: caloriesToDisplay.productList)

        return calorieCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let calorieHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieHeader") as! CalorieHeader

        let headerTitle = calorieSectionTitle[section]
        calorieHeader.dailyTotal.text = "\(headerTitle)"

        return calorieHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let calorieFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieFooter") as! CalorieFooter

        // Test 1
        let sectionTotal = dailyCalories[section].getTotal()
        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "\(sectionTotal)"
        // places "0" as total in all the footers cells when passed

        // Test 2
        let calculate = String(dailyCalories.map{$0.productList.calories}.reduce(0.0, +))
        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "\(calculate)"
        // gets overall total for all the cells in every section and places the overall total in every footer

       // Test 3
        var totalSum: Float = 0
        for eachProduct in dailyCalories{
            calorieTotalArray.append(eachCalorie.productList.price1)
            totalSum = calorieTotalArray.append.reduce(0, +)

            calorieFooter.calorieTotal.text = String(totalSum)
        }
        // gives different totals in each section. But its not accurate and it constantly changes when scrolling up and down

        return cartFooter
    }

}
```

---

```
class CalorieTracker {

    private(set) var items : [DailyCalories] = []

}

extension CalorieTracker {
    var total: Float {
        get { return items.reduce(0.0) { value, item in
            value + item.subTotal
            }
        }
    }

    var totalQuantity : Int {
        get { return Int(items.reduce(0) { value, item in
            value + item.subTotal
        })
        }
    }    
}

class DailyCalories {

    var productList : ProductList!

    var addCalorieCells = [ProductList]()
    var subTotal : Float { get { return Float(selectedCalorie) * Float(productList.count) } }
    var selectedCalorie: Int!

    init(productList: ProductList) {
        self.productList = productList
    }

    func selectedCalorieItem() {
        selectedCalorie = Int(Float(productList.calorie))
    }

    func getTotal() -> Float {
        var total: Float = 0

        for item in self.addCalorieCells{
            total = total + Float(Float(item.count) * item.calorie)
        }        
        return total
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your model and segregate your model sections index wise OR in your viewDidLoad when you are assigning groupedCalorieItems at that time calculate the sections total and store in array!

Below code is for Model change, initialize this like groupedCalorieItems.

below code is only by my assumptions only :P

```
Class SectionWiseCalories {
      var dailyCaloriesArr : [DailyCalories]!
      var caloriesTotal : Float!

      init(_ products : [ProductList]) {
           // map your data here & manage your caloriesTotal
       }

}
```

Comment: im been testing the ```class SectionWiseCalories```, Ive been getting  stuck on how to work it to add u the total of all the cells in section in the footer using the init for ```SectionWIseCalories```to get it work with my CartVC

Comment: when you're initialising SectionWiseCalories then at that time you're getting the product list for that section , so traverse  the array at that time and save the data in caloriesTotal var

Comment: okay okay. yeah I figured it out I just needed some time to figure it out